# Constructor parameters mutated by other Initialized within constructor

Tags: c#

This is my class constructor and i'm initializing two other classes within it.

```
public class APiBLL
{
   private cParams _cParams  

   private customer _adapter;
   private company _adapterCompany;

   public APiInboundBLL(cParams cParams)
   {
       _cParams = cParams;

       _adapter = new customer(_cParams);
       _adapterCompany = new company(_cParams);
    }

}
```

Within Company class constructor additional property is added to `cParams`

```
public company(cParams cParams)
{
    cParams.schema = "client";
}
```

Issue =>
Newly assigned value(parameter property) should reflect only within `_adapterCompany`.

But it's reflecting(Mutating) on `_adapter` as well.

Comment: seems `cParams` (horribly name by the way)  is a reference-type. Changes to any of the references will be reflected by all other references - that's the entire point why we call them ReferenceTypes. Either make your class a `struct` (=valuetype), or create a new `cParams`-instance when you provide it to the constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I can't make it struct since these are autogenerated codes from our framework.. A solution maintaining current structure is preferred

Comment: `company` class needs to maintain its own copy of `cParams` then. No way around that. OR it must create/use a composite that adds only this one parameter locally.

Comment: ^^ btw. Why isn't `schema` a private property of `company`, then?

Comment: Clone _cParams before you send it into company. `new company(Clone(_cParams));` You need to write the Clone function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You're reassinging the parameter in the company constructor. Instead create a local variable and assign it.

```
string company_schema;

public company(cParams cParams)
{
    company_schema = "client";
}
```

Comment: static is a really bad wording here, as your variable isn't static - at least not in the syntax-meaning, but just in semantics.

Comment: static or non-static changes nothing while the variable is of a reference type.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy true, but from turbos code the variable is just non-static.

Comment: I replaced the word static with local as it was admittedly badly worded.